# Add value to input file

Tags: cakephp

I want to add a field for my File Uploads to see the diffrence between preview and just normal files.

Right now I can´t see the difference, just these Information. But I need a 'preview' => 1 or something. Maybe there is a simpler way to notice the diffrence.

I am getting this in Cakephp

```
'name' => 'test.jpg',
            'type' => 'image/jpeg',
            'tmp_name' => '/tmp/phpqq3nhC',
            'error' => (int) 0,
            'size' => (int) 3633405
```